# rsync options so that source and dest are exactly the same?

Tags: rsync

My `src` folder is my local laptop.

I have a `dest` folder which I use for backup (and is NAS mounted) but for historical reasons I have sometimes used the `dest` folder for exactly what I use now `src` (bear with me).

The result is that I have for example

```
src/docs/2021/january.pdf
```

while

```
dest/docs/2021/february.pdf
```

I just happen to run `rsync -av src/ dest`, and the result now is

```
src/docs/2021/january.pdf
src/docs/2021/february.pdf

dest/docs/2021/february.pdf
```

What I'd like to achieve though is that the 2 are completely synced, so that both have the january and february files (in other words that the `dest` files are also synced to `src`).

How do I do that?

Comment: You have to do two rsyncs, one in each direction

Comment: That looks like an answer! I thought about that but I was wondering if that was really the case. Thanks. You are welcome to provide this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two rsyncs, one in each direction.

Comment: That [won't work](https://superuser.com/a/1712408/332907)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `rsync` for this case unless you can guarantee never to delete any files.

Consider two trees, `A` and `B`.

- Copy all the files from A to B (synchronisation). We can't delete anything in `B` because it might be a file that needs to be copied to `A`.
- Copy all the files form B to A (synchronisation the other way). We still can't delete anything in `A` because it might have been created just now and needs to be copied back to `B`.

Now `A` and `B` are synchronised, with a copy of everything that was in `A` now in `B`, and everything that was in `B` now in `A`.

Let's assume you want to delete a file from `A`. Now repeat the synchronisation and notice that the deleted file has reappeared in `A`. This is because it was still present in `B` and got copied across as if it were a new file.

One solution to this is to use a different tool. I've had good results with [`unison`](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison) (also [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/)), which was created as a bi-directional synchronisation tool. (There are some other tools around but I can't remember them offhand.)

Synchronise two trees `A` and `B` as simply as with this command

```
unison A B
```

There are options available to determine how to act when the same file has been updated on both sides, etc.

Comment: Or you delete the file in both trees when you delete it.

Comment: @mpez0 well yes, but that's yet another way to accidentally delete the wrong files from your backup

Comment: you wouldn't do a two-way synch for a backup.